# UISplitViewController detailview changing result is gray area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ipad

I am trying to replace the detailview of a UISplitViewController for a quite a while now, but the solutions I found on the internet wasn't useful.

I am executing this:

```
DetailViewController* secondVc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.splitViewController.viewControllers];
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:secondVc];
[self.splitViewController setViewControllers:arr];
```

DetailViewController is just a normal UIViewController (is this the problem?) I chose red as its background but I am seeing a completely gray area in the detail view after this code is executed.

What surprises me is that viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear functions are called for the DetailView class, but I can't see it on the screen. The self.view.frame is 0,0,768,1024 although all my settings are in landscape mode in storyboard.

I only want to use this in landscape mode, I don't need a generic solution.

What is the most basic way to change the detail view of a split view controller? I have looked at Apple's MultipleDetailViews but that felt like overkill since most of the code in it is about responding orientation changes, like hiding the master vc etc.

Comment: Where are you making DetailViewController's view? In a storyboard or xib? In code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is using alloc init to instantiate secondVC -- that would work if you made your controller's view in code, or in a xib with the name "DetailViewController". Since it appears that you're using a storyboard, then you should be using,

```
DetailViewController* secondVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"]; // be sure to use this same identifier in the storyboard
```

Comment: I can't believe how I missed this and I can't thank you enough :)

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard, select the view controller. On the right side, go to "Simulated Metrics" and pick "Detail" for "Size". As for the color, try setting it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yes I have done that, thanks for pointing out. The color worked fine with rdelmar's solution.